# How to know db size at runtime

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i'm trying to know the database space available.
In J2ME you have getSizeAvailable(), but there is no direct replacement in Android, so i thought about doing getMaximumSize() minus database size, the thing is i just can't find a way to know the db actual size, at runtime.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656417/how-to-determine-android-database-max-size-and-prevent-sqlitefullexception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`android.os.StatFS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html) to find the available space. [Here is some sample code](http://www.androidsnippets.org/snippets/48/index.html) that demonstrates its use.